# Visually hide content but not pseudo content

Tags: css

I'm using a pattern like this to add icons via `:before` or `:after` pseudo content:

```
<span class="icon icon__example is-content-visually-hidden">assistive text</span>
```

How can I visually hide the assistive text without hiding `.icon` pseudo content? Neither the assistive text or the space it occupies should be seen at all, such that these icons can be used inline. When`.is-content-visually-hidden` is toggled off then the text should be visible. I tried various techniques such as `text-indent: -9999px` to no avail.

**[This codepen demonstrates the problem](http://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/EaEzVO)**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simple approach is to set inner text's `font-size` to `0` and then reset pseudo-element font to normal again to make it visible:

```
.is-content-visually-hidden {
  font-size: 0;
}

.icon__star::before {
  content: "*";
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxWQRX

However more flexible approach is to wrap text into one more span:

```
<i class="icon icon__star is-content-visually-hidden">
  <span>star</span>
</i>
```

and hide `span` only.

Comment: Right on. I [played with it](http://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/EaEzEz) and it seems to work with hard units like `px` and `rem` but not with dynamic ones like `em` or `calc(1em)` or with `inherit`. Using ems or inheriting the parent `font-size` would be ideal but still this solution rocks.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you can't use em or % or inherit for obvious reason: parent font-size is 0. So this is kind of pitfall of course. I would actually use <span> solution as it's more comprehensive.

Comment: I agree the extra `span` is a nice pattern. We're trying to use as few elements as possible.

Comment: Setting the state to `.0000000001em` and the pseudo to `10000000000em` [works in Chrome 40 to get the correct relative size but doesn't seem to work in FF35 or IE11](http://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/vERwbg)

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the inner text in a span and hide that to be sure. But if you are not able to do that then you could try

```
font-size: 0
```